# Unixtime conversion with multiple unix timestamps - only the first timestamp gets converted

Tags: javascript, unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp

First time posting a question on SO. Forgive me if I'm not explaining my problem well or have some dumb errors in here.

Consider the following array of UNIX timestamps and code:

```
// UNIX timestamps have been multiplied by 100 already so that Date() can be used to convert them to human readable timestamps
var times = [144414720000, 144423360000, 144432000000, 144440640000, 144449280000]

for (var i = 0; i < times.length; ++i) {
    var converted = Date(times[i]);
    console.log(converted);
}
```

This returns "Tue Oct 06 2015 11:50:44 GMT-0400 (EDT)" five times.

It seems that the Date() only worked on the first element inside the array, and then was duplicated? Why doesn't this return an array of correctly converted, unique, human readable timestamps? How do I change this code so that it does?

Comment: you are getting the current date 5 times, not the first one...

Comment: ah yeah... good point